# only one usercontrol instance specified in datatemplate

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I have specified a userControl as a dataTemplate.

```
<TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pages}">
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <uc:ItemTemplateControl />
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The userControl is very easy and just binds to a string property, which works fine.
But the strange thing is, there's only a single instance created of the userControl (debugger in ctor hits only one time), even though I have multiple items...

How can I create separate userControl instances for each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work when you specify the dataTemplate directly in the tabControl.
You must specify the dateTemplate as a separate resource.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting your user control inside repeater control and bind the repeater control with your data source. For example,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeatInfo" runat="Server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <Your control/>
     </td>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```